# After 3 interviews invited for an interview months from now

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

I had virtual interview rounds first with recruiter, then manager, then company head officials and HR. The job is for a new venue opening months from now and they asked this time for an in person interview at the opening time of the venue (2 months from now).

No offer was made (to be honest the job ad stated most of but not all the package content).

What should I expect from this? Is this a normal procedure or something unusual? Was it just an excuse or might they be interested in hiring?

---

They did ask me for i person interview but 2 days later they decided to move on.

thank you all for your answers.

I guess one lesson here is have an interview and offer now not 2 month from now.

Comment: "Was it just an excuse or might they be interested in hiring?" We're not psychic. We don't know. "What should i expect from this?" You should expect nothing. Continuing to look for work and continuing to interview with other potential employers is the only rational response. Ignore the parts you can't control and focus on the parts that you can.

Comment: Do they tell you the reason they schedule the next interview months from now ?

Comment: If you think that your time is better used to prepare for interviews with other company, then you can cancel this next interview with this company. We don't know how you feel about this company. You can search the web to see if this company has a good reputation of treating employees well in terms of work-life balance, salary, and career growth.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 yes because the venue is opening months from now.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk What i meant is is this a normal procedure or something unusual. You are right that one should focus on what they can control.

Comment: So, why can't the company invite you to their current venue or office right now to have the in-person interview ? Or don't they have a physical office right now because everyone is working remotely (from home) ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 they do have an office and all but not sure why they wont invite now. like i said the business i am suppose to work in opens in couple of months. maybe they are gathering candidates at this time? not sure. id hope someone might clue me in

Comment: Sounds like it is on the other side of summer vacation.  Accept the invitation and if you don't get something else in the meantime, go to the interview when the time comes.

Comment: @workstuff11 the only people that know for sure are the ones doing the hiring. Why does it matter if it's normal? What is normal anyway?

Answer (score 7):

I would assume that they would like you to come to an interview in two months time, which may lead to a job offer at some point, which then may take more time until you start working and get paid.

If you are actively looking for a new job, continue applying at places, having interviews, and hopefully getting a new job. I hope that will be all done before two months. If not, and you are still interviewing in two months time, there is no reason not to go to an interview with them.

Comment: "I would assume that they would like you to come to an interview in two months time" nope. see my answer.

Comment: workstuff11: You _would_ assume that they want you to come to an interview. Assumptions can be wrong, but lots of people block their own chances by assuming something underhanded is going on.